# How to have my users add song to an album in django

Tags: python, css, django, django-models

I am trying to be able to add songs through a form but keep getting

> NOT NULL constraint failed: post_song.album_id.

As of right now I can only add songs ramdomly and they aren't connected to the original album.

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import  settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Album(models.Model):
    creator = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_photo = models.FileField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name ='album_post')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.creator + ' - ' + self.album_name

class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    song_name= models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.song_name
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

## views.py

```
class SongAdd(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['song_name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.album_id = self.request.GET.get('album_pk')
        return super(SongAdd, self).form_valid(form)
```

## details page

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {% include 'post/form-template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Well, where is the album value supposed to come from?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass then id of an album when storing the song in the database?

Comment: @CarlosAfonso new updated code addresses that but  It still doesnt connect to the parent album

Comment: Have you created and ran a migration yet?

Comment: @CarlosAfonso yes it is now it's able to add songs but they aren't connected to any album.

Comment: I believe you're supposed to pass an Album instance to `form.instance.album` instead of the `album_id`. Try fetching the album instance from the album id and passing it to `form.instance.album`.

Comment: okay tried a couple of different ways but I don't fully get how to do it ( i am a beginner) but here is what i was able to come up wtih     album= Album.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = AlbumForm(instance=album)  I dont know what to add in the models.py

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

### views.py

```
class SongAdd(CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['song_name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        album = Album.objects.get(pk=album_id_variable)
        form.instance.album = album
        return super(SongAdd, self).form_valid(form)
```

Make sure `album_id_variable` is a valid album id.

Comment: that works thank you! I still have to try and learn more about it is there any place where i can read up on this more

Comment: You can check [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/) itself. It's a great resource. Furthermore, don't forget to choose an answer for your question to flag this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you are missing the album field. The form does not know what album you want to associate the song to.

Comment: A solution would be adding a combo box (`<select>`) to your form with all albums available in your database

Comment: I made an attempt at it today i was able to add songs but they they don't have a parent album

Comment: You should remove the code in form_valid() where you set the album manually. Django will automatically set the album to the one you selected in the form.

Comment: How so? because thats the probkem i have right now .                                   def form_valid(self, form):
        album= Album.objects.get(pk)
        form.instance.album= album
        return super(SongAdd, self).form_valid(form)